# Icinga2 : Installation Error date.timezone is not defined

Tags: icinga2

Installation of Icinga2 Monitoring Tools on Ubuntu 14.04

I am not able to complete my installation.
I am getting the Error **"The PHP config `date.timezone' is not defined."**

I did the changes on /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

date.timezone = Asia/Kolkata

After the changes i restart my webServer apache also.
service apache2 restart

Still i am facing the same issue when i am launching [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7nBC.png)http://localhost/icingaweb2/setup

Comment: You maybe have to change it in `/usr/share/icinga-web/pub/index.php`.

Comment: have you removed the ; at the beginning of the line? That one got me

Comment: @VikeeKumar is your Question answered?

Answer (score 0):

I think the timezone has to be placed in (single)quotes, like:

```
date.timezone = 'Asia/Kolkata'
```

Answer (score 0):

The Solution is.

```
nano /etc/php/7.3/apache2/php.ini

[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions

; http://php.net/date.timezone

date.timezone = "Asia/Nicosia"
```

Remove the semicolon from the front of the date.timezone and then set the value to one that you need for your locale. And then restart the Apache server.

/etc/init.d/apache2 restart